# In vi/vim, how do I append to a file instead of overwriting it?

Tags: text-processing, vim, vi

I know I can write to a file by simply doing `:w <file>`. I would like to know though how can I write to a file by appending to it instead of overwriting it.

Example use case: I want to take some samples out of a log file into another file. To achieve that today I can do:

1. Open the log file
2. Select some lines with `Shift+v`
3. Write to a file: `:w /tmp/samples`
4. Select some more lines with `Shift+v`
5. Append to `/tmp/samples` with `:w !cat - >> /foo/samples`

Unfortunately step 5 is long, ugly and error prone (missing a `>` makes you lose data). I hope Vim has something better here.

Comment: If you're interested in using Vim better, do checkout sister site [vi.se].

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [`:h :w`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aw):

```
                                                :w_a :write_a E494
:[range]w[rite][!] [++opt] >>
                        Append the specified lines to the current file.

:[range]w[rite][!] [++opt] >> {file}
                        Append the specified lines to {file}.  '!' forces the
                        write even if file does not exist.
```

So, if you have selected the text using visual mode, just do `:w >> /foo/samples` (`:'<,'>` will be automatically prepended). If you miss out on a `>`, Vim will complain:

```
E494: Use w or w>>
```

Comment: This is perfect :)
Nothing like reading the docs. Didnt know about `:h` though. Will use it more

Comment: @BrunoPolaco `:h` is just shorthand for `:help`. Start with [`:help helphelp`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#helphelp)? :D

Comment: This is great when building shell scripts in combination with the `fc` command.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function:

```
fun! App(filename)
    exec "w !cat - >> " . shellescape(a:filename)
endfunc
```

Call a function:

```
call App('/foo/samples')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Append all contents of current file to file named filename

```
:w >> filename
```

## Append contents in line numbers 1 through 13  of current file  to file named filename

```
:1,13w >> filename
```

Comment: This seems to be a comment on [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274231/116858)